# How to coalesce frames with mencoder in QGIS Time Manager plugin?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I need some guidance putting the exported frames together from the QGIS Time Manager plugin.

I saw your line about mencoder, so I downloaded it along with mplayer, but I'm not sure how to use them.

The .exe files do not open a program after being run.

A bit more detail on this?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to explain the connection of "Time Manager" to GIS, please? Is it a component of a particular GIS software?

Comment: Yes, Time Manager is an experimental plugin in QGIS

Answer (score 1):

MEncoder is a command line tool and [the Time Manager Video Tutorial readme shows how to use it](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/blob/master/VideoTutorial.md):

> A good option is MEncoder. This is how it's used to create an .avi from all images within a folder:
>
> ```
> mencoder "mf://*.PNG" -mf fps=10 -o output.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4
> ```